# Why flv file body use PreviousTagSize rather than NextTagSize?

Tags: decode, flv

The flv stucture is like this:

```
FLV header
PreviousTagSize0 - Always 0
Tag1
PreviousTagSize1 -  For FLV version 1, this value is 11 plus the DataSize of the previous tag.
Tag2
...
PreviousTagSizeN-1 - Size of second-to-last tag
TagN(FLVTAG Last tag)
PreviousTagSizeN - Size of last tag
```

why not like this:

```
FLV header
NextTagSize0 - Tag1 size
Tag1
NextTagSize1 - Tag2 size
Tag2
...
NextTagSizeN - Size of last tag
TagN(FLVTAG Last tag)
```

I think NextTagSize is more convenient for decode!

Answer (score 1):

I think flv tag list in flv body is designed as double linked list. The PreviousTagSize represents the back node point. Actually, the 'NextTagSize' is already included in current node (DataSize syntax in tag header), and it can point to the next node.

With double direction linked points, it will be easy and fast to seek previous or latter media packets.